# How to display local Indian languages in from unicode?

Tags: android, fonts, components, locale, indic

I am trying to display **local Indian languages** in my application. The data for the application is **from web**. I use a web service to display the contents from DB. I am converting the data in format of unicode and i receive the **unicode** in phone. Am trying to display the unicode and also i use the relevant **font** If **telugu** i use telugu fonts. 
The unicode is displayed but there is **spacing problem**. To solve this i got a option of **reshaping**, that is like giving space with fixed codes and  got for Arabic but i am now searching for **telugu**.

My reffered link is:
[Refference for Arabic](http://blog.kerul.net/2010/12/connected-arabic-characters-for-android.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can put in HTML codes for the devanagari characters. There are quite a lot of online editors that will give these codes, like:
-> http://www.wandel.person.dk/hindi.html
(A text editor which you can use to write devanagari characters)

-> http://vikku.info/indian-language-unicode-converter/hindi-unicode-converter.html
(An english to hindi text converter)

Answer (score 0):

Use Typeface option. Please see an example below

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "myfont.ttf"); 
text.setTypeFace(font);
```

Comment: But the text displayed was not in readable format. Experienced problem with spacing between texts.